# A Fancybox gallery containing both inline content and a video

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

Is it possible for a fancybox popup gallery to contain both a video and inline content ? So clicking on my link will popup a window, showing first a paragraph(inline content), and then the user will press the next arrow in the popup window to get to a video (in the same popup window). I couldnt find an example anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a gallery in fancybox with different `type` of content :

- images
- videos
- inline content
- iframes

etc.

Just make sure that all your links share eithr the same `rel` or `data-fancybox-group` attribute like :

```
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?autoplay=1&wmode=opaque">This open a video</a>
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="#inline">this open inline content</a>
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg">this open an image</a>

<div id="inline" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Inline Content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Then you could use a simple script like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        //API options here
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/24caT/)**

**Notice** that the youtube video is using the `embed` format so we added the special fancybox's class `fancybox.iframe` to open the video in `iframe` mode

Comment: Thanks for the respone JFK. However, I want to display only one link, not three. The one link should first open to inline content, and then the user presses the arrow navigating to the video, in the same popup window.  Is this possible ?

Comment: @user2197774 : yes, it's possible ... however you still the links to every type of content that can be hidden in a `<div>`, see updated http://jsfiddle.net/24caT/1/